# How to implement a search function in my Application that have a sqlite database?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-recyclerview

I wanna add a search function in my application, unfortunately I'm very new in programming and I'm not really sure how to put a search function in my application fragment that is connected to my SQLite database.

I know how to show my data from sqlite to recyclerview but I dont really have any idea how to add a function that will kind of sort my data based on the search of the user. Please help me!

This is my xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".AttendanceFragment"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:background="#3876BF">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Attendance"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="50dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ScrollView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp">

                    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:id="@+id/attendanceRecyclerView"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

                </ScrollView>

            </LinearLayout>

        </ScrollView>

    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

This is my code in a fragment that shows my data.

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton;
import androidx.core.view.MenuItemCompat;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.SearchView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.checkerframework.checker.units.qual.A;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class AttendanceFragment extends Fragment {

    RecyclerView attendanceRecyclerView;
    MyDatabaseHelper myDatabaseHelper;
    ArrayList<String> id, student_number, student_name, time, date;
    AttendanceAdapter attendanceAdapter;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_attendance, container, false);
    }

    //show the data in the recyclerView
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        attendanceRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.attendanceRecyclerView);

        myDatabaseHelper = new MyDatabaseHelper(getActivity());
        id = new ArrayList<>();
        student_number = new ArrayList<>();
        student_name = new ArrayList<>();
        time = new ArrayList<>();
        date = new ArrayList<>();

        storeAttendanceInArrays();

        attendanceAdapter = new AttendanceAdapter(getActivity(), id, student_number, student_name, time, date);
        attendanceRecyclerView.setAdapter(attendanceAdapter);
        attendanceRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    }

    public void storeAttendanceInArrays() {
        Cursor cursor = myDatabaseHelper.readAttendanceData();
        if (cursor.getCount() == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No attendance history", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                id.add(cursor.getString(0));
                student_number.add(cursor.getString(1));
                student_name.add(cursor.getString(2));
                time.add(cursor.getString(3));
                date.add(cursor.getString(4));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is my adapter.

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class AttendanceAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AttendanceAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList id, student_number, student_name, time, date;

    AttendanceAdapter(Context context, ArrayList id, ArrayList student_number, ArrayList student_name,
                      ArrayList time, ArrayList date) {
        this.context = context;
        this.id = id;
        this.student_number = student_number;
        this.student_name = student_name;
        this.time = time;
        this.date = date;

    }
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.attendance_row, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.numberTextView.setText(String.valueOf(student_number.get(position)));
        holder.nameTextView.setText(String.valueOf(student_name.get(position)));
        holder.timeTextView.setText(String.valueOf(time.get(position)));
        holder.dateTextView.setText(String.valueOf(date.get(position)));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() { return id.size(); }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView numberTextView, nameTextView, timeTextView, dateTextView;
        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            numberTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.numberTextView);
            nameTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.nameTextView);
            timeTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.timeTextView);
            dateTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.dateTextView);
        }
    }
}
```

and this is my database helper codes.
This one is for creating the table.

```
String query2 = "CREATE TABLE attendance_table(" +
                " id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL," +
                " student_number INT NOT NULL," +
                " student_name TEXT NOT NULL," +
                " time TEXT NOT NULL," +
                " date TEXT NOT NULL" +
                " );";
        db.execSQL(query2);
```

This one is for showing the data.

```
Cursor readAttendanceData() {
        String query = "SELECT * FROM attendance_table ORDER BY date DESC";
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = null;
        if (db != null) {
            cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        }
        return cursor;
    }
```

Lastly this is my new code for searching the specific data based on date, but I dont really know how I can use it.

```
Cursor searchDate(String date) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM attendance_table LIKE '%" + date + "%'";
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);

        return cursor;
    }
```

My expected output is that I can add either a searchView or a spinner that will let the user pick what data they wanna see in the recyclerview